# Run-time error 9 in vba

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

Good day, I'm pretty much new in VBA, and I have a problem with path specifying, consider the following:

```
x = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "06-17.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value
```

With this piece of code I have run-time error 9, but if I use the following code it works fine:

```
Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "06-17.xlsx")
x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value
```

I have founded that run-time error 9 means that elements of arrays and members of collections can only be accessed within their defined ranges, but how it relates to my case, I have no idea. 
Why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index to the `Workbooks` collection is the file **name** (or an integer number), not the file **path and name**.

So `Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "06-17.xlsx")` would not be valid (because it includes the path), but `Workbooks("06-17.xlsx")` will be valid.

This is the reason why (or, at least, related to the reason why) you can't have two workbooks open in Excel at the same time if they have the same file name, even if they have been opened from two different directories.

Answer (score 2):

In the second example, the workbook is open when the second line executes.
In the first example, there is no assurance that the workbook will be open at the time of execution.

Comment: Ok, but why this doesn't work:  Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & "06-17.xlsx") /n clientNumber = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & " / " & "06-17.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value?

Comment: @Maksim  do we have ***Cells(i, 1)*** or ***Cells(1, 1)***

Comment: Oh, no i just have a loop, Cells(1, 1) , the main problem is that I have opened file, but when I call Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & " / " & "06-17.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value this line of code it doesn't work, The run-time error 9

Comment: @Maksim  On my computer I had to reverse the *slash* and remove the spaces ***Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "BA.xlsx")*** to get working code.

Comment: Public Sub a()
    MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "06-17.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "06-17.xlsx")
    x = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "06-17.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
End Sub

Comment: I think the main problem is with ThisWorkbook.Path it doesn't work. When I use exactly the same procedure in the default directory it works fine, I mean without ThisWorkbook.Path

Comment: I have also checked directory and path is valid, I have no idea what is wrong with ThisWorkbook.Path